# Turn a list of words into cells in a Word table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a script that takes all my misspelled words and pastes them into a new document so now I have a document file with every word being a misspelled word. There are currently 167 words in that document. I have also made a script that can make tables. I now want to put each of those 167 words into its own cell with the result being a table with 167 cells and each cell containing one word.
The goal would be to automate this so that any number of words in a given document could be converted into a table.

How could I go about doing this? I know that the answer would have something to do with loops which is why this is the farthest I have gotten.

```
 Sub TurnInToTable()
 Dim actdoc As Document
 Dim newtbl As Table
 Dim aword As Range 
 Dim x As Integer 
 Set actdoc = ActiveDocument
    x = actdoc.Words.Count
 Set myrange = actdoc.Range(0, 0)
 Set newtbl = actdoc.Tables.Add(myrange, x, 2, wdWord9TableBehavior)
 For Each aword in actdoc.Words
 ?????
 Next aword
 End Sub
```

The plan is to eventually have a table with two columns: One with the misspelled words and the other with the correct spelling so that I can easily add all the pairs into the auto-spellcheck dictionary at the same time.

Comment: Get the range for your misspelled words then do a convert text to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have pasted each word into a new paragraph there is no need to loop through anything. You simply need to convert the paragraphs into a table:

```
Sub MispeltWordsTable()
   With ActiveDocument.Content
      With .ConvertToTable(Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, NumColumns:=1, _
         NumRows:=.Paragraphs.Count, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
         .style = "Table Grid"
         .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
         .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
         .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
         .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
         .Columns.add
         .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
         .PreferredWidth = 100
      End With
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't  have each word into a new paragraph. Every single misspelled word is on the document page just like a regular document is. With one word after another.

Comment: @CountSpergulia - then just do a find and replace first to replace all the spaces with paragraphs, and edit your routine that builds the document so that it puts each word into a new paragraph.

Comment: @CountSpergulia - when you design a coded solution you need to keep in mind what your end goal is. In this instance that means either building a document that is easy to convert to a table, or you build the table as you go adding a new row for each word you want to add. Just dumping words into a document when you ultimately want to have them in a table is illogical.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your advice. I just started coding for the first time 3 days ago. I would give you an upvote, but I don't have enough reputation to do so!

Comment: @CountSpergulia - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)